# How to Detect Current Workgroup in Workgroups2?

Tags: elisp

I was looking through the code and found `wg-current-workgroup-p` ("Return `t` when `WORKGROUP` is the current workgroup, `nil` otherwise.") which seemed to be what I want, but if the current workgroup is called "main" and I do

```el
(wg-current-workgroup-p "main")
```

I get `nil`. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding the function. I couldn't find a way to get the current workgroup name either. I'd also like to be able to do this with the workgroup index as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wg-current-workgroup-p` doesn't take a string as the workgroup name, it needs to be passed an actual workgroup object. For example, try doing this:

```
(wg-current-workgroup-p (wg-current-workgroup))
```

`(wg-current-workgroup)` returns the current workgroup as a workgroup object. Obviously, this will return true, because you're checking if the current workgroup is the current workgroup.

Some examples:

You can get a list of all workgroup objects with `(wg-workgroup-list)`.

To check if the current workgroup is the last one in the list:

```
(wg-current-workgroup-p (car (last (wg-workgroup-list))))
```

To get the name (as a string) of the first workgroup, you can do this:

```
(wg-workgroup-name (car (wg-workgroup-list)))
```

You can get all the workgroups names as strings with `(wg-workgroup-names)`

`helm-apropos` is useful for finding all these functions.

Comment: I actually did look at these using helm (though thanks for mentioning helm-apropos; I wasn't aware of it), but wg-workgroup-name isn't documented. What I wanted was (wg-workgroup-name (wg-current-workgroup)). Thank you.